Where can I ask about the Chinese language and its characters?
I would like to learn about Chinese language, especially about the signs where I can't even imagine how these strokes meet up to make a character.
Is there a site on Stack Exchange where I can ask about that?
If not, where else should I go to?

This Meta site is not the right place to ask your Chinese language question. We do, however, have a Chinese Language site; see their on-topic page to see if your post is a good fit there. If not, then unfortunately, we don't have a site on our network where it'd fit.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog of course the Meta is not the place to ask my questions about Chinese language. My question here was where (and how) I should ask them. I would be especially interested (where to ask for) how the strokes in Chinese characters are made and placed. If this turns out to be a "Chinese people only site" then I will respect this and quit immediately.

We do get a lot of people asking off-topic questions that they intend to ask on another site here, so that explains the first part of my comment. Also, it's not a Chinese people-only site, as the on-topic page there says.

Did you try putting stack exchange ask about chinese into a search engine? For me, that gives the correct Stack Exchange site as the first result. It also happens to be named exactly what one might expect, and can also easily be found by ctrl-F on the list of Stack Exchange sites. I don't understand why this needed to be asked here.

I could not find this my question yesterday any more. Did I look the wrong way?

Questions about Chinese may be asked on Chinese Language Stack Exchange. While the majority of questions on that site are about Mandarin Chinese, questions are allowed pertaining to any of the Chinese languages/dialects, including Cantonese and Min. Make sure to read their Help Center to confirm that your question is on-topic and in good shape before posting.

Thank you. I was asking this on Meta to be polite and not ask impropriate questions on the main site.
